# Make complains about "no such file or directory" when building a kernel module

Tags: kali-linux, drivers, make

```
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.10.0-kali7-amd64/build M=/var/lib/apt/lists/rtl8812au modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/5.10.0-kali7-amd64/build: No such file or directory. Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:2244: modules] Error 2
```

---

This message shown when I need to make when need to install drivers to run alfa any can help.

Comment: Are you asking what you need to type in order to make that error appear (title)? Or How to resolve the error? Perhaps you can give a little bit more setup about your problem and the commands you ran to get to this point.

Comment: See also: [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](//unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/112566)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the kernel header files for your specific kernel version.

Run

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

and try to compile the module again.